# VSCode displaying freshly cloned files as modified with gutter indicators

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I recently had some issues with my local github repository, so I deleted the entire folder (including all the .git files) and cloned a new fresh copy. However, when I open the files in VScode, the code does not match what is on the online github repository. Instead the actual updated code I want is displayed in gutter indicators. The code that isn't in the gutter indicators is an old version of the code. However, if I open the files in another editor not linked to github, it displays the file correctly. I suspect it might be related to a local commit or stash, but I am fairly new to github so I am not sure what to do.

Or possibly a vscode [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77387)?

I tried git revert and hard reset, but so far nothing has fixed it. Also, if I try to save I get a VSCode error: "**Failed to save 'filename': The content of the file is newer. Please compare your version with the file contents.**"

This is an Angular project by the way (not sure if that matters)

**EDIT** I fixed it. I just completely removed and reinstalled all the add-ons on VSCode. So I guess it wasn't a git issue, just some kind of bug with VS Code

**EDIT2** Turns out it didn't fix all of it, because I am still getting some gutter indicators, even though it removed some of them.

**EDIT3** I did `git rm --cached . -r -f` in the local repository and then completely recloned it again. Seemed to remove all the gutter indicators so far...

Comment: if you rename the `.git` folder in the repository to `.git-org` do you see the content you want? Rename it back after the experiment.

Comment: Yea, if I rename the git folder, I see the file displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try and:

- clone a fresh copy in a new folder (separate from your old one)
- Add that new folder to your VSCode workspace with "[`Add Folder to workspace`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)"
- open files from the ones displayed in Explorer tab.

Those files should be the updated ones, not the old ones.

Comment: Thanks this worked! However, this means I can no longer work on my project in the directory I originally wanted to place it in, even if I completely remove and redownload all the files. Is it some kind of cache issue related to vsCode?

Comment: You did should be able to rename the folder, and reuse the same name for a New clone, and reference it in a new VSCode workspace.